Is the gospel offered to everyone?
For those that believe some are predestined to reject Christ, is the gospel still offered to them?

@NigelJ - true. I made it bare bones

I don't understand the close votes, myself.  This is a very simple and fundamental question for those who accept reprobation. +1

Nowhere in scripture does it say the gospel was only offered to the elect or only offered to the Jews.  Even during Christ’s ministry, where before his death the theocracy was still in place, Gentiles took a secondary position until his death  but not an excluded one.  (example Matthew 15 and the faith of the Caananite woman)
Jesus also knew his wider purpose to the world so when he used phrases like ‘God so loved the world ‘ John 3:16 and  ‘Come to me all who are heavy laden’ Mat 11:23 did not exclude any non-Jews listening to his words.
Did his words exclude those not chosen?
Matthew 22:11-14

“But when the king came in to see the guests, he noticed a man there who was not wearing wedding clothes. He asked, ‘How did you get in here without wedding clothes, friend ?’ The man was speechless.
“Then the king told the attendants, ‘Tie him hand and foot, and throw him outside, into the darkness, where there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth.’
“For many are invited, but few are chosen.”

This is simply a fact that many hear the gospel and are thereby invited but few believe it. However they were genuinely invited. The gospel is offered not insincerely or with hidden deception but plainly.  We have an example of those not chosen yet being offered the gospel.
However we have a doubt.  John 6:44 NIV:

“No one can come to me unless the Father who sent me draws them, and I will raise them up at the last day.

Some of those called and who came to the wedding feast did not come genuinely by faith.  Not all are covered in the right clothes through justification by faith.  This means they were not actually ‘drawn by the father’ but came improperly not by faith. Those that come by works for example. These are not ‘drawn by the father’. They don’t have the right clothes.
In conclusion the scriptures do offer the gospel to all that hear it, it is good news to all men (Luke 2:9-12):

But the angel said to them, “Do not be afraid. I bring you good news that will cause great joy for all the people. Today in the town of David a Savior has been born to you; he is the Messiah, the Lord. This will be a sign to you: You will find a baby wrapped in cloths and lying in a manger.”

The gospel is nothing but joy offered for all.
Besides the scriptural evidence that the gospel is offered to all, a person must actually believe so to be saved.  Practically speaking. I do not mean they must believe so after they are saved to remain saved.  Why must a sinner believe the gospel is offered to all? Because they must believe in Christ, not in a difficult doctrine to understand called predestination. They need to believe it is offered for them and it is cruel to burden them with any other ideas.
The gospel is nothing but joyful news offered to all and simple enough for a child to understand.

Re: John 6:44 -- How does God (the Father) draw people? I believe the answer to this is via "Moses and the prophets" (i.e. the OT), as Jesus' story of Lazarus mentions, and the presentation and "lifting up" of Christ (Who thereby also "draws all people to [Himself]"). It's not some mystical enabling of their spirit to be able to respond to the gospel.
